# Continuity on a closed interval

Tags: calculus

The function f:R--->R is is defined as 
$f(x) =1$ , $ |x|$ $ ≤$ $1$

$=2x $ when $|x|>1$

Is f(x) continuous on the interval $[-1,1] $

My take it is continuous in the closed interval because here we check if  the  LHL at x=1 =f(1)
And RHL at x=-1 =f(-1)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hi i've editted the post thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the number in the interval $(-1,1)$ satisfy $\mid\  x\mid\leq1$. Therefore for all $x\in(-1,1)$, $f(x)=1$, which is continuous.

For $x=-1$, $\lim_{x\to-1^+}f(x)=1$ and $f(-1)=1$, therefore $f$ is left continuous.

Similarly for $x=1$, $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=1$ and $f(1)=1$, therefore $f$ is right continuous.

$\therefore\ f$ is continuous at $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Hi i have one question if you might answer here we need to see if LHL of 1  is equal to f(1) right and RHL of -1 is equal to f(-1) right we don't need to check the LHL of -1 here if i'm right ? @vAn

Comment: My bad, yes, we need to check the LHL of the upperbound ($x=1$) and RHL of the lower bound ($x=-1$).

Comment: Thankyou so much !